# Objective C: OpenAL using .CAF

Tags: objective-c, ios, openal

Good day! i have a question regarding .caf files in openAL path...is it possible to use .caf file in openAL? because when i use a current .wav file in the filepath it actually run.. but when i use .caf.. it doesnt have errors but when i run it, it says:

```
2012-07-25 17:46:18.314 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error setting audio session category! -50
AudioStreamBasicDescription:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved
2012-07-25 17:46:18.638 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.668 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.741 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.753 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.834 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.846 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.869 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:18.879 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-25 17:46:20.053 openALplaybackTRY[20432:10a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x148f022 0x1aaccd6 0x1437a48 0x14379b9 0xe0a53b 0xe0a4c5 0x6dc4 0x7243 0x68b5 0x6ea135 0x7e9c6e 0x7e98f1 0x7e9383 0x58dfd0 0x6ea135 0x7e9c6e 0x7e9383 0x6e9c76 0x7e9c6e 0x7e967b 0x7e9383 0x6e9105 0x8f2eef 0x8f303e 0x4c7d7a 0x4c7ff8 0x4c717f 0x4d6183 0x4d6c38 0x4ca634 0x3ad0ef5 0x1463195 0x13c7ff2 0x13c68da 0x13c5d84 0x13c5c9b 0x4c6c65 0x4c8626 0x24fd 0x2465)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

> Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

and this is my code:
aolPlayback.m  @initBuffer(actually from apple)

```
// get some audio data from a wave file
    CFURLRef fileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:@"Alice01" ofType:@"caf"]];
```

Comment: any ideas why i got SIGABRT when i change my type into .caf from .wav?

Answer (score 0):

CAF is a container format, not an audio format. The audio data contained within the caf file must be little endian signed 16-bit uncompressed PCM data to load directly into OpenAL.

If it's not in that format, you'll need to convert it after loading. Here's a class that does this (for iOS but it should be simple enough to modify for Mac): https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/OALAudioFile.m

The benefit of loading and then converting is that you can keep the audio data compressed on disk, thus lowering the distribution size of your app. I use AAC compression for my audio data.